# How to package a single-file executable using the SQLite EF Core Database Provider on .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I would like to write an app using the [SQLite Entity Framework Core Database Provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/), package it as a single-file executable (i.e. a single exe file without any .dll files around) and having it to run on .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it involves a lot of work, both at build time and at runtime.

First, you'll have to use the [Costura](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/) Fody add-in for embedding references as resources. Add this to your csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Costura.Fody" Version="4.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Doing so will automatically package all dlls inside your main executable and load them at runtime. Everything works out of the box for managed dlls but native dlls require some more work. Costura can take care of preloading native libraries if we embed the native libraries in directories named `costura32` or `costura64`. With some MSBuild magic, we can embed the native sqlite dlls provided by [SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3/) (which is an indirect dependency of the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/) package):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3" Version="2.0.4" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="EmbedNativeSQLiteDllWithCostura" BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="$(PkgSQLitePCLRaw_lib_e_sqlite3)\runtimes\win-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll">
            <Link>costura32\e_sqlite3.dll</Link>
            <Visible>false</Visible>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="$(PkgSQLitePCLRaw_lib_e_sqlite3)\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll">
            <Link>costura64\e_sqlite3.dll</Link>
            <Visible>false</Visible>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <Content Remove="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)' == 'e_sqlite3.dll'" />
        <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)' == 'e_sqlite3.dll' OR '%(Filename)%(Extension)' == 'SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll'" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Let's break it down.

First we need an explicit `PackageReference` to `SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3` with [`GeneratePathProperty="true"`](https://blog.dangl.me/archive/accessing-nuget-package-paths-in-your-net-sdk-based-csproj-files/) so that we can access the native sqlite dll paths.

Then we embed the x86 and x64 native libraries in the `costura32` and `costura64` so that Costura automatically loads them at startup (even before the `Main` function is called).

We also need to remove the `e_sqlite3.dll` files from the `Content` item else all the native dlls are copied in the output directory. We don't need them in the output directory since we will use the embedded ones.

Last, we need to remove both `e_sqlite3.dll` and `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll` from the `ReferenceCopyLocalPaths` item so that they are not embedded as Costura resources. `e_sqlite3.dll` is a *native* library and we have already embedded it. `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll` must not be embedded because we will write our own SQLitePCLRaw initializer and we don't want EF Core to run the default `Batteries_V2.Init()` initializer.

That's it for the build part. Now let's see what must be done at runtime.

Since we prevented `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll` to be embedded by Costura, the default initializer [will not run](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v3.1.8/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/Utilities/BundleInitializer.cs#L18-L31) (`Assembly.Load` will return `null`). We must therefore [configure a SQLite provider](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/tree/v2.0.4#a-trio-of-packages) before using a `SqliteConnection`. We will re-use the `SQLite3Provider_dynamic_cdecl` (coming from the [SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl/) package) and configure it with our own implementation of the `IGetFunctionPointer` interface. Our implementation searches for the `e_sqlite.dll` module of the current process that was automatically loaded by Costura and uses the `NativeLibrary.TryGetExport` method from SQLitePCLRaw:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using SQLitePCL;

public class ModuleGetFunctionPointer : IGetFunctionPointer
{
    private readonly ProcessModule _module;

    public static ProcessModule GetModule(string moduleName)
    {
        var modules = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>().Where(e => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.ModuleName) == moduleName).ToList();
        if (modules.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Found no modules named '{moduleName}' in the current process.", nameof(moduleName));
        }
        if (modules.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Found several modules named '{moduleName}' in the current process.", nameof(moduleName));
        }
        return modules[0];
    }

    public ModuleGetFunctionPointer(string moduleName) : this(GetModule(moduleName))
    {
    }

    public ModuleGetFunctionPointer(ProcessModule module)
    {
        _module = module ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(module));
    }

    public IntPtr GetFunctionPointer(string name) => NativeLibrary.TryGetExport(_module.BaseAddress, name, out var address) ? address : IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Finally, at the very beginning of the program, we need to initialize the SQLitePCLRaw provider:

```cs
const string name = "e_sqlite3";
SQLite3Provider_dynamic_cdecl.Setup(name, new ModuleGetFunctionPointer(name));
SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLite3Provider_dynamic_cdecl());
```

With everything in place, the SQLite EF Core Database Provider can be used in a single-file executable on .NET Framework. Full working [sample code](https://gist.github.com/0xced/701bcfec9c54bc0c151a365923b74e69) is available for reference.

Note that if you are targeting .NET Core instead of .NET Framework, none if this is required. [Publishing a single-file executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview) will work out of the box.

Comment: How do you include unmanaged files with .net Core single files?

Comment: I think it can be achieved by using `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` + `<Link>` with the proper *runtimes* path, see how it's done in the the [SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/blob/v2.0.4/src/SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3/SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.targets) for example.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks